# Azure Bot Service: "An internal error occurred at the server."

Tags: azure-bot-service

I'm testing bot services. I created bots the last week and all were normal but yesterday the service was unavailable.

[Error internal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1m4eS.jpg)

Hope someone can help me.

Comment: This is a recent bug currently being addressed. 
 Please see: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/3630  for progress and updates.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with the bot service. My solution was to create the bot service in a new account, without tenants suscriptions. I gave access to the new account to my tenant suscription, when the new account created the bot service, it works. The new account was an outlook account.

Hope it could be usefull for someone.

Two week to solve this, and I think the Microsoft's support didn't help.
-10 Microsoft support.

Comment: The fix for this has been released.